# What settings prevent AllocConsole from being included?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I've created a new windows universal dll project in VS2015. I'm trying to use AllocConsole() to create a console window, but I'm getting the errors

```
error C3861: 'FreeConsole': identifier not found
error C3861: 'AllocConsole': identifier not found
error C2065: 'FILE': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'stdout': undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'freopen_s': identifier not found
```

This is after including windows.h, and wincon.h, and consoleapi.h (not sure what this is, F12 took me to it)

I'm guessing it's a project setting that's preventing this from working?

Comment: "new windows universal dll project" prevents this from working, you cannot use the console in a UWP app.  Along with a large number of other winapi functions, the kind that are not compatible with mobile devices that run off a small battery.

Comment: Thanks, I was entirely ignorant of that. I assumed it was just a newer wizard path to the same old thing. Specifically selecting the old win32 project type and choosing DLL allowed me to make a project that was not neutered.